# Conditional IE8 style in original CSS file?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

How can I override this styling for just IE8 browsers (I don't think I care too much for IE7 users anymore unless if the markup is very minimal)?

```
#menu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:650px;
    }
#menu ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:110px;
    padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#e5e5c3;
    }
```

Obviously, IE8 and below doesn't render display inline-block on li elements so how can I conditionally override this in this original CSS file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use a conditional html tag to add a class if the browser if IE and target via specificity, load an ie8 only stylesheet or use a CSS hack `\0/` to target IE8 only.

I suggest the head route if you only have a couple one-off issues in IE.

**HTML Class Method**

In your `HEAD`

```
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

In your CSS

```
.ie8 #menu ul li {
    display:block;
    width:110px;
    padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#e5e5c3;
    }
```

**IE8 only stylesheet method**

Load AFTER your common shared styles.

```
<!--[if IE 8]><link href="/css/app-ie8.css" type="text/stylesheet"/> <![endif]-->
```

**IE8 CSS hack**

use \0/ directly after selector

```
#nav li ul  {
  left: -39px\0/ !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using separate style sheet for this. or either you can use embedded styles in html as follows

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<style>
#menu ul li{
....
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{path to your ie-8 override css}" />
<![endif]-->
```

There is a another hack mentioned [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/).